Incident flux in a plane wave
As mentioned in Nuclear Structure by Bohr and Mottelson
Flux of incident particles associated with waves normalized per unit energy is
$$(\rho v)_\text{incident channel} = p^2/(2\pi\hbar)^3$$
How does one get it?

Thanks for edit
